# How to remove multiple columns from a dataframe with column list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a variable list with column names and a dataframe . I would like to remove columns from the dataframes when the column names match the variable list.

columns -> "a","c"
dataframe->

```
a b c d  
0 0 1 1  
1 1 1 1
```

Ouput->

```
b d  
0 1  
1 1
```

Please help me out with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select_` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7. See the `select_` docs for  more info.

I believe the new recommended approach is to use a select helper verbs.

Using shadow 's example. it would be:
`select(dataframe, -one_of(c("a", "b"))`

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Anders Swanson pointed out that you can now use `select` with standard evaluation. So the following works:

```
select(dataframe, -columns)
```

**Previous version**

You can use `select_` together with '-' as shown below:

```
# create data 
columns <- c("a","c")
dataframe <- read.table(text="a b c d
0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 ", header = TRUE)
# load dplyr package
require(dplyr)
# select columns
select_(dataframe, .dots = paste0("-", columns))
```